# recv() blocks from second call

Tags: c, linux, sockets, recv

I have a simple client-server app for sending files from client to server.
The client sends the file in chunks of predefined size (say 512).
The server receives the file also in chunks with the same size.
The socket on the client side isn't closed until the server sends an ack after receiving the entire file.

What happens is that:

1. the client manages to send (send() call) the entire file, means all its chunks.
2. the server manages to get (recv() call) only the first chunk, means recv() call returned 512 on the first call and on the second call it blocks.

What might be the cause for such behavior?

Here are the relevant parts.

Send\Receive functions:

```
int sendBuf(int sockFd, char* buf, int size){
    int bytesSent = 0;
    while (bytesSent < size){
        bytesSent += send(sockFd, buf, size, 0);
    }
    return bytesSent;
}


int sendInt(int sockFd, int num){
    uint32_t nbo_num = htonl(num);
    return sendBuf(sockFd, (char*)&nbo_num, sizeof(nbo_num));
}


int getBuf(int sockFd, char* buf, int size){
    int bytesRecv = 0;
    while (bytesRecv < size){
        bytesRecv += recv(sockFd, buf, size, 0);
    }
    return bytesRecv;
}


int getInt(int sockFd, int *num){
    int temp, bytesRecv;
    bytesRecv = getBuf(sockFd, (char*)&temp, sizeof(int));
    *num = ntohl(temp);
    return bytesRecv;
}
```

Server:

```
printf("%s     New file was created.\n",tStr);

/* get file data */
char buf[FILE_READ_CHUNK_SIZE] = {0}; // FILE_READ_CHUNK_SIZE is the maximal read amount
int bytesWritten = 0, bytesLeft = fileSize, _size=0, chunkNo=0;
bytesRecv = 0;

while (bytesLeft > 0){
    _size = (bytesLeft > FILE_READ_CHUNK_SIZE) ? FILE_READ_CHUNK_SIZE : bytesLeft;
    bytesRecv = getBuf(newsockfd, buf, _size);
    int _bytesLeft = bytesRecv;
    bytesWritten = 0;
    while (_bytesLeft > 0){
        bytesWritten = fileInfoWrite(fileInfo, buf, _bytesLeft);
        _bytesLeft -= bytesWritten;
    }
    chunkNo++;
    printf("%s     chunk #%d: received %d bytes\n",tStr , chunkNo, bytesRecv);
    bytesLeft -= bytesRecv;
}
printf("%s   Finished getting file #%d.\n",tStr ,i+1);

/* send ack to the client */
bytesSent = sendInt(newsockfd, 1);
printf("%s   Sent the client an  ack for file #%d.\n",tStr ,i+1);
```

Client:

```
/* send the entire data of the file */
printf("  Sending file data\t\t... ");
char buf[FILE_READ_CHUNK_SIZE] = {0}; // FILE_READ_CHUNK_SIZE is the maximal read amount
int numOfChunks=0, bytesRead = 0, bytesLeft = filesArr[i]->fileSize ;
bool eof = false;
bytesSent = 1;

while (bytesLeft > 0){
    bytesRead = fileInfoRead(filesArr[i], buf, &eof);
    int _bytesLeft = bytesRead;
    while (bytesSent < _bytesLeft){
        bytesSent = sendBuf(sockFd, buf, _bytesLeft);
        _bytesLeft -= bytesSent;
    }
    //printf("    chunk #%d: sent %d bytes\n", numOfChunks+1, bytesRead);
    bytesLeft -= bytesRead;
    numOfChunks++;
}
printf("Success.\n");

/* get ack from server */
int ack=0;
bytesRecv = getInt(sockFd, &ack);
if (bytesRecv!=4 || ack!=1){
    printf("Server ack is invalid.\n");
}
printf("Finished sending file #%d.\n",i+1);
```

Comment: The most likely issues here are either the network dropping/filtering stuff, or a bug in your code somewhere.

Comment: If the network was filttering anything then it should had filtered the first chunk also. A bug is always a possiblity, but of what kind? It is the same code for all chunks as their are sent\received in a loop...

Comment: There are as many possible bugs in C code as there are characters in its source file (possibly even more than that). Without seeing the relevant parts of your code, no-one can help you.

Comment: @Mat - I added few source lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sending code is wrong, it won't send more than one chunk under normal circumstances (i.e. the write writes a full chunk in one go).
This is because you don't reset `bytesSent` after the inner loop. Chances are it is going to be `== FILE_READ_CHUNK_SIZE` after the first `sendBuf`, and the while condition will always be false after that.

So you're only sending one buffer.

(There are probably a few more errors in your code. You'll be sending the wrong parts of the buffer if a short write happens (you'll resend the head of your buffer) for instance.)

Comment: Thanks allot Mat! You found my bug :)